# @Protocol with 2 elements

Tags: objective-c

What does

```
@protocol UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource;
```

mean ?

Does it mean UIPageViewControllerDelegate and UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocols have some methods and properties in common ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@protocol UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource;
```

is equivalent to...

```
@protocol UIPageViewControllerDelegate;
@protocol UIPageViewControllerDataSource;
```

Just like...

```
int x, y, z;
```

is equivalent to...

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some context of where you found the would help.

It looks like a forward declaration of two protocols and their being in the same statement does not imply an association. The same as `int x, y` does not imply any connection between x and y.